Avalonia UI Set DataContext of Control in ContentControls DataTemplate
I am using a ContentControl with DataTemplates where a template selector (based on IDataTemplate) is choosing which DataTemplate to apply.
My template selector selects the correct template and also shows it. My problem is, that the DataContext is not inheritted to the Control from within the DataTemplate. If I put the control from within the DataTemplate in place of the ContentControl, it works and the DataContext is inheritted.
How do I give the DataContext of the UserControl to the controls within the DataTemplate of ContentControl?
The XAML code looks like this:
 <UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:My.Avalonia.ViewModels"
         xmlns:v="using:My.Avalonia.Views"
         xmlns:dt="using:My.Avalonia.DataTemplates"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="400" d:DesignHeight="800"
         x:Class="My.Avalonia.Views.MainView"
         x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel"
         >
  <ContentControl
    Content="{Binding SelectedPage}"
    >
    <ContentControl.DataTemplates>
      <dt:MainViewTemplateSelector>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DisruptionsView">
          <v:DisruptionsView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- More Datatemplates are here -->
      </dt:MainViewTemplateSelector>
    </ContentControl.DataTemplates>
  </ContentControl>

</UserControl>

And this is the template selector:
public class MainViewTemplateSelector : IDataTemplate
{
    // This Dictionary should store our shapes. We mark this as [Content], so we can directly add elements to it later.
    [Content]
    public Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate> AvailableViews { get; } = new Dictionary<string, IDataTemplate>();

    // The Keys of the DataTemplates for the views.
    private List<string> _ValidViews = new List<string> { "DisruptionsView" }; // Here are more in reality

    // Build the DataTemplate here
    public Control Build(object? param)
    {
        var key = param?.ToString(); // Our Keys in the dictionary are strings, so we call .ToString() to get the key to look up
        if (key is null) // If the key is null, we throw an ArgumentNullException
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(param));
        }
        return AvailableViews[key].Build(param);// finally we look up the provided key and let the System build the DataTemplate for us
    }

    // Check if we can accept the provided data
    public bool Match(object? data)
    {
        if (data?.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            if (_ValidViews.Contains((string)data)) 
                return true;

            return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}

EDIT: ADDITIONAL Information
If I replace the ContentControl with an ItemsControl and adjust the SelectedPage Variable to be a string[] with just one object, it works. It just breaks the style as the ItemsControl item cannot use a * for the RowDefinition height.
What is the difference of the DataTemplate handling between ContentControl and ItemsControl?
This works:
  <ItemsControl
    Grid.Row="1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedPage}"
    >
    <ItemsControl.DataTemplates>
      <dt:MainViewTemplateSelector>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DisruptionsView" x:DataType="v:MainView">
          <v:DisruptionsView DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=mv}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LinesView">
          <v:LinesView />
        </DataTemplate>
      </dt:MainViewTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl.DataTemplates>        
  </ItemsControl>


I found a solution. In the ContentControl use a ContentTemplate instead of a DataTemplate. If you do that, you can bind the DataContext property of the view without getting a StackOverflow exception at runtime.
So my solution looks like this:
Adding a x:Name="mv" to the root tag and change the ContentControl as follows (ContentTemplate property of the Content Control instead of DataTemplate and the DataContext binding at the view in the DataTemplate tag:
  <ContentControl
    Grid.Row="1"
    Content="{Binding SelectedPage}"
    >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
      <dt:MainViewTemplateSelector>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DisruptionsView" x:DataType="v:MainView">
          <v:DisruptionsView DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=mv}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- ... -->
      </dt:MainViewTemplateSelector>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
  </ContentControl>


Thank you.  I learned what ContentControl should bind to Content property, not DataContext.
